# Is it possible to "Mirror" the look of a decision tree generated with rpart.plot in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, rpart

I have generated a simple decision with `rpart` and displayed it with `rpart.plot` like the following.

[image: Decision Tree]

Is it possible to edit the look of the tree so it's "mirrored" like the following:

```
         (e-100%)
____(yes)___|___(no)____
|                       |
|                     (e-53%)
(p-47%)               __|__
                     |     |
                  (p-1%)  (e-52%)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the parameter `xflip=TRUE` to `rpart.plot` function flips the tree horizontally like intended